# Android - default messaging app SMSs time is recieved time not sent

Tags: android, database, sqlite

first of all this is my first time asking a question here so sorry in advance if i'm a bit off the guidelines... i'll try to make it as clear as possible:

I'm writing an application that transfers SMSs from one device to another (both devices are android devices). i noticed that on some devices, when i enter the default messaging application the date next to each message thread is not the date that the Sms was recieved at the first device but the date when the message was received in the 2nd device.

***for ex***.: Let's say the date is 17/02/2015. if at this date i'm transfering a Sms message from 1/1/1970 from device A to B so when i'll enter the default messaging application in device B (considering that he is one of the 'problematic' devices) i'll see next to the 'message thread' containing the Sms will be 17/02/2015 (and not 1/1/1970).

the 'problematic' devices i've found where LG G2 mini & Nexus 4, there might be more. also i know there's an open issue for that topic at google (see link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2989).

**So finally, my question is this:**

after some research i've extracted the mmssms.db database (containing the device sms, located in '/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/') from a 'problematic' (nexus 4) device and comparing it to a 'non-problematic' (Samsung Galaxy S3) device **i've noticed that there is a difference in one of the Triggers of that db: 'sms_update_thread_on_insert'. 
in the problematic device, the trigger contained : "date=(strftime('%s','now')*1000)" and in the non-problematic device that trigger contained: "date=new.date)**.

so i'm suspecting that this might be the source of the problem.

is there any way of altering / dropping a database trigger on an android device programatically & without the device needing to be rooted? or alternatively, is there any way to bypass a trigger on a db in android?

Thanks in advance and sorry if i've exhusted you with this very long post...:)

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way of altering / dropping a database trigger on an android device programatically & without the device needing to be rooted?

Only if it is your database. In this case, it is not your database. You only have access to this database's contents through a `ContentProvider`.

> is there any way to bypass a trigger on a db in android?

At best, only if it is your database. In this case, it is not your database.

Moreover, there are *thousands* of Android device models. Please do not assume that the behavior that you see on these two devices represent the sum total of all behavior that can be seen on all of the devices.